# Preventing Compiler from optimizing code without the use of volatile

Tags: c, gcc, kernel

I'm trying to create a kernel from scratch (just trying something new)

Everything is ready now and I'm testing the output and noticed something very weird

I build my files with:

```
gcc ./kernel/kernel.c -ffreestanding -O0 -m32 -c -o./bin/kernel.o -fno-pie
```

and link them together with:

```
ld -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -Tlink.ld ./bin/kernel_ep.elf.bin ./bin/kernel.o -o ./bin/kernel.bin
```

So from my understanding, I already tell the compiler NOT to optimize my code.

Now the C part

```
#define BYTE unsigned char
#define VIDMEM ((BYTE*)0xb8000)

void init();
void main() {
    init();
    while(1);
}

void print(char *msg)
{
    volatile BYTE *screen = VIDMEM;
    for(const char *msgPtr = msg; *msgPtr; ++msgPtr)
    {
        *(screen++) = *msgPtr;
        screen++;
    }
}

void init() {
    //volatile char test[] = "Test";
    //print(test);
    print("Test");    
}
```

If i run this, nothing will happen, I checked the whole thing in ghidra - the char array of "Test" is in the memory, but I have no reference to init() -> So `print` never gets called.

If I now use the commented text (and comment `print("Test")`) everything works fine, text gets printed the way I want.

But the real question is: Is there some kind of "Trick" to tell the compiler NOT to optimize this code except using volatile? because I don't think declearing everything which could maybe be printed as volatile is the way I should do this.

As far as I understand, the main problem is that the `print` function basically does nothing, because the compiler doesn't seem to know that 0xb8000 is a kinda... special adress.

Answer (score 3):

1. This Microsoft style of defining the types is just horrible. Use exact size types like `uint8_t` or `int32_t`.  Defining `BYTE` is a very bad habit. It will no cause problems here but the problem starts with wider types and different sizes on different systems.
2. The compiler will inline both functions in this trivial example. So you will not see the `init` or `print` function calls. If you want to make it noninlineble use `__attribute__((noinline))`.
3. you do not need volatile as the code will not be optimized.

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define VIDMEM ((uint8_t*)0xb8000)


void __attribute__((noinline)) print(const char *msg)
{
    uint8_t *screen = VIDMEM;
    for(const char *msgPtr = msg; *msgPtr; ++msgPtr)
    {
        *screen++ = *msgPtr; 
    }
}


void __attribute__((noinline)) init() {
    print("Test");    
}


void main() 
{
    init();
    while(1);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/iqNadv

Here you have the inlined version. Function are static to prevent compiler from having another copy for the external linkage.

https://godbolt.org/z/giKAnC

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, I'm already working on the removal of the BYTE and DWORD (and so on) definitions (I'm writing this with some friends) but the change you suggested unfortunatly did not work.
I also agree with you that the code should not be optimized, but I found no other explanation because if a declare the char as volatile, it works. 
Do you have any other recommendations? (No i did not vote down your answer...)

Comment: Show the actual code - that where it is actually optimized.

Comment: @P__J__ I didn't downvote but I think the reason this doesn't work is because there's another byte needed for the color.

Comment: @P__J__ I can offer you a github link with all the sourcefiles: https://github.com/shiro-os/shiro-kernel/tree/master/kernel
We only have C code in this directory
If its easier for you, i can just copypaste everything together...

Comment: where is the suspect (file:line)

Comment: @P__J__ https://github.com/shiro-os/shiro-kernel/blob/master/kernel/kernel.c#L36 That would be the "entry point" the printf() function is in util.c (the header is included)

Comment: @P__J__ Yeah, I'm pretty sure. I wrote some code a while back that dealt with VGA video memory and it needed a byte for the color. Here's the link for anyone interested: https://github.com/JL2210/newboot (mainly in `src/x86/` and `include/newboot.h`). But based on a comment from another answer this is dealt with already, so your answer might be right.

Comment: @S.S.Anne but it is not about any particular hardware, only about the memory mapped hardware access. It does not matter what is placed there. It is a bit higher level of abstraction. Or assume that is OPs video card,. No  colour needed\

Comment: @P__J__ The 0xb8000 region is reserved for the VGA text-mode video memory. It's set up at boot. The color is every second byte.

Answer (score 0):

Your `volatile` char array is on the stack, while your string literal is not. I suspect that you have incorrectly set up your data segment register. I'll go ahead and clone your repository and test that theory out.

Comment: Well, thanks you very much for you effort - I also thought that the .data segment COULD be the culprit, but I lack the knowledge to actually confirm this.

Answer (score -2):

While compilers used to treat integer-to-pointer conversions as indicating points where compilers shouldn't assume anything about the resulting pointer (essentially implying volatile semantics in the case where the result of each act of conversion was only used once) neither clang nor gcc provides any option to support such semantics except `-O0`.

Comment: Elaborate it. It is handled just fine by gcc and all embedded world just benefit form it.

Comment: @P__J__: Given `int x = *(char*)0x1234; x+=*(char*)0x1234;` both gcc and clang will perform one read and then add `x` to itself if optimizations are enabled.  I know of no option other than disabling optimization to tell them to meaningfully process source code which is designed for compilers that offer stronger behavioral guarantees than mandated by the Standard.

Comment: The problem is that I already tell the compiler to use `-O0` maybe I'm doing something wrong while linking / compiling but I'm not shure what exactly is wrong here.

Comment: @supercat This example shows that you do not really understand what the side effect is. If you don tell the compiler that something can be changed by something not visible to the compiler - it will not read it twice. But the OP question is not about it. Another way is to place the compiler memory barrier (clobber) `int x = *(char*)0x1234; asm("":::"memory");x+=*(char*)0x1234;` https://godbolt.org/z/-hkPQE

Comment: @P__J__: Until gcc and clang started requiring it, a lot of code which used int-to-pointer cast expressions for things like I/O register accesses omitted the `volatile` since it served no purpose but to make the code bulkier and slower to compile.  The only way I know of to make such code work usefully and reliably in clang and gcc is to completely disable optimization.